# enzyme test / react for keyDown (shift) for stopImmediatePropogation

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, onkeypress

I am trying to test stopImmediatePropogation() when the KeyDown event - Shift is pressed .

```
enter// wrapper.simulate('keypress', { key: 'Shift' });
wrapper.simulate('keydown', { keyCode: 16 });
const stopPropogation = jest.fn();
expect(stopPropogation).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);

wrapper.find('.className').simulate('keyDown', { key: 'Shift' });


// const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { keyCode: 16 });
// // const dispatchStopProp = jest.fn();
// document.dispatchEvent(event);
// // expect(dispatchStopProp).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
// const result = wrapper.dive().instance().stopPropogation();
// expect(result).toEqual(1);

// const onKeyDown = sinon.spy();
// const wrapper = mount(<TestComponent onkeydown={onkeydown}/>);
// const input = wrapper.find('input');
// input.simulate('keyDown', { keyCode: 16 });
// expect(onKeyDown.called).to.be.true; code here
```

None of my ways seem to work . Any suggestions will be helpful .

Motive to unit test :

stopPropogation() is called when keyboard "shift" key is clicked on the app page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to track a stopPropagation in your you can't just declare a jest.fn with the same name and track it.

You need to spy on the function, I like to use SinonJS.

Example:

```
var spy = sinon.spy(MyComponent.prototype, 'stopPropagation');
// Do something that invokes MyComponent.stopPropagation

expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
```